# Should back-end service be accessible to client when routing is used?

Tags: wcf

My understanding on routing service in WCF is this -

The actual services resides in your private network which is not accessible to the world. You then have a routing service as an intermediary which internally (based on inspecting the request) calls the services in protected environment. This routing service is accessible to client and client uses this routing service to communicate with actual services.

Hence, how will the client know about the service contract exposed by the back-end service (as explained in most of the articles on routing)? If from WSDL, then client will anyway know about base address of back-end service and directly call the service instead of routing service. How can we enforce this constraint on client side?

Thought?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in said cases, you will expose the service contract through other means, such as a statically published WSDL. This is going to be more prevalent in scenarios in which you are using mechanisms such as protocol transitions, as the original, dynamically-generated metadata is going to be wrong anyhow.

For simpler scenarios (in which all you want to do is avoiding exposing your server directly to the network), a reverse proxy might be a preferable alternative in some cases if you're using HTTP.